# [Google::Apis::DriveV3 ]Get uploaded file URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, google-drive-api, rubygems

I would like to get URL that uploaded to Google Drive using 'google_drive' gem in rails.

I tried to get that from returned value that created but there were no such a link but API link so you cannot access to Google Drive.

Is there a method to get that link?

This is returned link, not this

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1m4Ja7qCNrfqhrkrtKibuPoV02Shp5w7G2?
```

I want this

```
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1ObHbN1heqwewgx1RkyEJ1Bm4GL3TSTjmI
```

Thank you.

```
require "google/apis/drive_v3"
require "googleauth"
require "googleauth/stores/file_token_store"
require "fileutils"

OOB_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob".freeze
APPLICATION_NAME = "upload-image-to-gdrive".freeze
CREDENTIALS_PATH = "credentials.json".freeze
TOKEN_PATH = "token.yaml".freeze
SCOPE = Google::Apis::DriveV3::AUTH_DRIVE


class DriveUploader
  def initialize
    # Initialize the API
    @@drive = Google::Apis::DriveV3
    @@service = @@drive::DriveService.new
    @@service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
    @@service.authorization = authorize
  end

  def authorize
    client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file CREDENTIALS_PATH
    token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::FileTokenStore.new file: TOKEN_PATH
    authorizer = Google::Auth::UserAuthorizer.new client_id, SCOPE, token_store
    user_id = "default"
    credentials = authorizer.get_credentials user_id
    credentials
  end

  def upload(name, image_source)
    file_metadata = {
        name: name,
        parents: ['1ObHbN11jdig94x1RkyEJ1Bm4GL3TSTjmI'] # Drive ID
    }
    file = @@service.create_file(
        file_metadata,
        fields: 'id',
        upload_source: image_source,
        #content_type: 'image/jpeg' # 'application/pdf'
        content_type: 'application/pdf' # 'application/pdf'
    )
    user_permission = {type: 'anyone', role: 'reader'}
    @@service.create_permission(file.id, user_permission, fields: 'id')
    file
  end
end
```

Comment: So if you to retrieve the folder where the file is contained rather than the file itself? I don't quite understand which link you want and what you mean by `you cannot access to Google Drive`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- After uploading a file your drive and retrieving its Id, you can use the method [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) in order to obtain the `file resource`.
- The file resource contains all the metadata of the file, as specified in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource)
- Useful for you might be e.g. the `webContentLink` or the `webViewLink`
- Both can be obtained by specifying them in `fields` for the `drive.files.get` method